# Table View Custom Cell... Giving the constrains but it is not working

Tags: uitableview, custom-cell

I created a table view controller with table view cell along with XIB file...Actual table should look like this ([image of Table view to be created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju2qA.png)). I gave all the constrains in the XIB file(screenshot attached) ([screenshot of XIB look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPoId.png)) but when i run the simulator the the table created is very messy and does not fullfil any of my constrains ([screenshot of table created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbcPr.png)).  What am i missing? is there any table view/ cell settings that i should change?

my constrains includes:
for Cast Image:
leading space to superview: 8
bottom space to superview: 5
top space to superview: 5
cast image proportional width to superview: 0.3

all four labels are placed in stackview and constrains like top space, leading space and trailing space set

logo image's bottom space and trailing space set to superview and width is set to 50 and height is set to 50

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seriously... Those screenshots.

Comment: What about the height of your cells?
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Comment: ya i have set that also in tableview controller file.. it is not only about the height but the labels, image everything is messed up

Answer (score 0):

I can't do more than write how it should be set up.

Profile image:

```
Set top bottom leading to super view, 8 offset on all.
Set width to superview with a multiplier of 0.3
Set contentType to scaleAspectFit
Set height to maybe 144?
```

stackview:

```
leading to profile image, maybe 8 offset here as well?
top to profile image top
trailing to superview
bottom to logo image
```

logo image:

```
bottom and trailing to super view offset 8
height and width to 50
```

Comment: i have set the same constrains as i have mentioned in my question but it doesn't help

Comment: Do you have contentType scaleAspect fit? and you need a height on image as well, (updated answer)